# Slow interactive interface/viewport

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I installed blender 2.79 and when i run it the viewport interact really slow it has a delay of almost 1 sec after i make any movements.
Im using AMD 12 Processor
Radeon R7 4Gb GPU
8 Gb RAM

IDK What to do.

Comment: Someone told me before i run the blender. Right+click mouse button then select Graphic Integrated Then your GPU.
But in my case i dont see something like what he said.

Comment: Please don't use all caps. It is considered yelling... http://netiquette.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_number_2_-_Do_not_use_all_caps

Comment: 1. How big is your blend file? 2. What is the viewport_mode you are in? (wireframe, solid,texture, material, render)? 3. What are you doing in blender when the viewport slows down? **TIPS:** A - Switch to wireframe or solid mode to get the fastest viewport experience: B - Here are a few hints to reduce slow 3D viewport drawing:
[Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/3d_view.html?highlight=viewport)

Comment: Add a screenshot or add the blendfile to your post through here:- https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com